# AFNetworking for WinObjC

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio, winobjc

Since Microsoft's WinObjC is still under development, they have not supported third party library like AFNetworking. Is there any other way around to use already existing AFNetworking in iPhone. And, is Pods supported in the latest WinObjC library?

Answer (score 6):

I work on the iOS bridge project at Microsoft. AFNetworking isn't currently supported so you won't be able to reuse those parts of your codebase at the moment, but it's a big priority for us and we're looking to add support in the next few months. You can see our current roadmap here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki/Roadmap

We also don't currently support CocoaPods since our clang compiler front end doesn't support virtual filesystems, which CocoaPods depends on. Again, this is a feature request we get a lot so it's a top priority for us.

Thanks for checking out the project – if you have any other questions, comments or suggestions, feel free to file issues on Github!

https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/

Comment: @noob-iOS, if this comment was helpful and answered your question, could you please mark it as accepted? If you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to reach out.